# How to eliminate first two numbers of a digit and how to get last 6 digits in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has eight digit numbers which start with `00******` or `********`
If the number starts with `00` I have to eliminate `00` and select the remaining 6 digits  and if data is without a zero at the beginning then I have to pick the first six digits of data. Please let me know how can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [faq] and [ask]. It always helps, when asking a question, to specify [what you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), so people are better able to help.

Comment: It appears that you have found an answer that works for you.  You ought to mark it as such.  (Do this by clicking the large greyed-out checkmark next to the answer.  It should turn green)

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Col,1,2)='00'
                     THEN SUBSTRING(Col,3,8)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(Col,1,6)
                END AS Col      
    FROM YOURTABLE;
```

Comment: Close, but in the second case he needs to trim it to the first 6 of 8 digits.

Comment: I was not the one that handed out that downvote.  Indeed, I think it unwarranted.

Comment: Possibly, the downvote was because of `SUBSTRING(Col,3,8)`. It should probably be `SUBSTRING(Col,3,6)`. (Although in this particular case both should work the same, as there are only 8 digits.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a `CHAR(8)` named `the_column`:

> SELECT IF(the_column REGEXP '^00', RIGHT(the_column, 6), LEFT(the_column, 6)) AS x
>   FROM some_table

```
+------------+
| the_column |
+------------+
| 00123456   |
| 87654321   |
+------------+


mysql> SELECT IF(the_column REGEXP '^00', RIGHT(the_column, 6), LEFT(the_column, 6)) x
FROM foo;
+--------+
| x      |
+--------+
| 123456 |
| 876543 |
+--------+
```